# AngularJS Custom directive How to access object value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Here is my html code where i am calling directive

```
 <div  ng-repeat="feat in templateAttributes track by $index">
                <md-input-container flex="50"> 
                   <feat-directive feat="{{feat}}" />

                </md-input-container>

 </div>
```

and below is custom directive code

```
sureApp.directive('featDirective', function () {
 alert("Hariom");
    return {

    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span style="padding-right:20px"><label value="{{feat.Name}}">{{feat.Name}}</label></span>',
    link: function(scope, element, feat){

        if(feat.DataType === 'Boolean'){
            element.append('<input type="text" id="{{feat.Name}}" value="{{feat.Value}}" ng-model="feat.Value" />');
        }
        else if(feat.AllowedValues && feat.AllowedValues.length > 0){
            element.append('<select ng-model="feat.Value" ng-options="x for x in feat.AllowedValues.split(\',\')"></select>');
        }

        else if(feat.DataType == 'Integer'){
            element.append('<input type="text" id="{{feat.Name}}" value="{{feat.Value}}" ng-model="feat.Value" />');
        }
        else if(feat.DataType == 'String'){
            element.append('<input type="text" id="{{attr.feat.Name}}" value="{{attr.feat.Value}}" ng-model="attr.feat.Value" ng-minlength="attr.feat.MinLength" ng-maxlength="attr.feat.MaxLength" />');
        }
        else if(feat.DataType == 'IpAddress'){
            element.append('<input type="text" id="{{feat.Name}}" value="{{feat.Value}}" ng-model="feat.Value" />');
        }

  }
  };                

});
```

But when i am trying to get the value of `feat.DataType` i am getting `undefined` while I am getting below values when debugging the code.

```
$attr
:
Object
feat
:
"{"Name":"DisplayName","DataType":"String","Description":"Display Name","Mandatory":true,"Editable":true,"Extension":false,"MinLength":3,"MaxLength":100,"AllowedValues":"","Value":""}"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Then i change code little bit like this

```
  link: function(scope, element, attr)
```

and tried used JSON parser

```
var feat1 = JSON.parse(attr.feat);
```

After this change below code showing `{{feat.Value}}` in inputbox

```
<input type="text" id="{{feat.Name}}" value="{{feat.Value}}" ng-model="feat.Value" />
```

Comment: `link: function(scope, element, feat){` this is wrong, the 3rd argument is for attributes of the element so it should be: `link: function(scope, element, attrs){` and then `attrs.feat`

Comment: @maurycy I tried that also and it have value `"{"Name":"DisplayName","DataType":"String","Description":"Display Name","Mandatory":true,"Editable":true,"Extension":false,"MinLength":3,"MaxLength":100,"AllowedValues":"","Value":""}"` and when trying to `access  attr.feat.AllowedValues` its coming undefined

Comment: just change `<feat-directive feat="{{feat}}" />` to `<feat-directive feat="feat" />` and you should be fine

Comment: btw: as far as I remember self-closing directives weren't fully supported (i'm not sure about latest versions of angular)

Comment: @maurycy after changing accroding to your suggestion i am getting attr value like this `$attr
:
Object
feat
:
"feat"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS directive creates it's own `scope`, you can access `parent scope` using `scope isolation`

[AngularJS docs for directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

you can add `scope` property in return

```
return {
 restrict: 'E',
 scope: {
    feat: '=feat'
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: if the attribute and scope value are the same you don't need to use the name just `feat: '='`

Comment: @maurycy Then how to include it any suggestion.

Comment: I think you can `try feat: '='` instead `feat: '=feat'`, in string with `=` sign represent `name of the attribute` in `directive`

Comment: @SanjayNishad Do you mean `sureApp.directive('featDirective', function () {
  
    return {
       
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
    feat: '=feat'
           },
    
    template:`

Comment: and remove `{{}}` to pass scope into directive, `<feat-directive feat="feat" />`

Comment: after changing accroding to your suggestion i am getting attr value like this $attr : Object feat : "feat"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135583/discussion-between-sanjay-nishad-and-subodh-joshi).

Comment: Only an isolate scope directive creates its own scope. If you pass `true` to scope, you will get a scope that inherits from the parent. Passing `false` will not create any scope. And passing an object will create an isolate scope.

Comment: @cst1992 So do you mean no need to create scope variable.only passing scope true will fine.